# Intent Filters with pathPattern

Tags: android

I have three activities that should open on three types of links

```
FirstActivity https://example.com/orders
SecondActivity https://example.com/orders/95
ThirdActivity https://example.com/orders/95/edit
```

In the intent-filter data i specified the following `android:pathPattern`

```
FirstActivity android:pathPattern="/orders"
SecondActivity android:pathPattern="/orders/.*"
ThirdActivity android:pathPattern="/orders/.*/edit"
```

Eventually

FirstActivity opens only on the first link - correctly

ThirdActivity opens only on the third link - correctly

SecondActivity opens on the second and third link - wrong

The problem is that tapping on `https://example.com/orders/95/edit` opens dialog, that offers to open both SecondActivity and ThirdActivity. And I need only the ThirdActivity to open.

What should I specified in the intent-filter of the SecondActivity, so that it opens only on the second link?

Comment: Are you saying that tapping on https://example.com/orders/95/edit is opening _both_ SecondActivity and ThirdActivity?

Comment: Yes, a dialog appears below that offers, along with the browser, two more shortcuts for opening the application. The first shortcut opens the SecondActivity, second the ThirdActivity

Answer (score 0):

In the `<intent-filter>` tag that matches your third link, add an `android:priority` attribute:

```
<intent-filter
    android:priority="1"
    ...>

    <data ... />

</intent-filter>
```

This should make it so that, when two different filters match a given link, only one of them is shown by the system.

Comment: No, there are still two shortcuts.